# C# trouble creating a table in console

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm struggle to get data to display in a table within a console application. I believe it may be something to-do with the way I am getting the data to display.

I'm using this to read the content of text files:

```
string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string[] textFiles = Directory.GetFiles(currentDir, "*.txt");
            string[] lines = new string[11];
            for (int i = 0; i < textFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                lines[i] = File.ReadAllText(textFiles[i]);
            }
```

Then I'm trying to display all the content of the text file into a table, each text file has 600 entries and they all go together to make a table.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,10} \t {1,15}", lines[0], lines[1]);
```

Was my attempt of getting them to display in a table but only the last entry of lines[0] and first entry of lines[1] are being put on the same line in console... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what are you expecting {0,10} to do? I just haven't seen this style of notation and don't understand it. All modifiers I have seen start with a letter and are invoked through {0:C2}.

Comment: @vipersassassin: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#FormatItem

Comment: You'll need to provide some sample input and output, basically a [mcve].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have 11 text files containing random data which only makes sense when paired in a table. As mentioned below i have to first find another way to store the data from the text files so i can manipulate it at a later date.

Comment: @RoyalsHF: *I have 11 text files containing random data which only makes sense when paired in a table.* Can you don't provide a small *representative* sample? Otherwise you are asking people to guess. Presumably your files are actually random, they have some kind of structure. What is that structure?

Comment: @MattBurland I explained this badly, each column of the table is located in the .txt files. A new column for every table, these columns contain: Ints, strings & doubles. Consider them random as that's just what they are unless pair with the other columns, (reading the first line from every text file will make up 1 set of data > there are 600 lines in each fine so a total of 600 lines of data when the columns are put together.

Comment: @RoyalsHF: So each text file is a single column with values separated by newlines then?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the entire contents of a file in a simple string, so that's what you'll get in that string - the contents of the file, including any new lines, tabs, spaces and so on. If you want to manipulate individual bits of strings within those files, you'll need to split those strings according to some rules first.

The formatting alignment you're using doesn't do all that much by itself - see Alignment Component in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: Okay firstly I will look for another method of getting my 11 text files into an array which allows me to manipulate easier, this was the only method i could get working to print the file content. I'm a novice C# programmer.

Comment: The method you chose is not wrong, it simply depends on what you want to happen next. If you want to work with each line in the file separately, then you need to split those strings into lines or read them directly as lines which is easier (ReadAllLines). If you make that change you will end up with an array which contains arrays so it gets more complicated, but then you can work with each line separately. If then each line contains tab/comma separated values and you need to work with each of them in turn, there are probably easier ways to get the data, like a CSV parser. As usual it depends.